# MongDB not starting

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mac.  I am trying to install MongoDB. I am not using Homebrew to install it. Program is stuck after running Mongod in the data directory /data/db directory on mac os x 10.12.6 macOS Sierra.

```
2017-09-20T16:52:33.204-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB 
starting : pid=1428 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Rohits-
MacBook-Pro.local
2017-09-20T16:52:33.204-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version 
v3.4.9
2017-09-20T16:52:33.204-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 
876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e
2017-09-20T16:52:33.204-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: 
system
2017-09-20T16:52:33.204-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-09-20T16:52:33.204-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build 
environment:
2017-09-20T16:52:33.204-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: 
x86_64
2017-09-20T16:52:33.204-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     
target_arch: x86_64
2017-09-20T16:52:33.204-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-09-20T16:52:33.205-0500 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data 
files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so 
setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-09-20T16:52:33.205-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open 
config: create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=20000,eviction=
(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=
(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy)
,file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=
(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-09-20T16:52:33.745-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-09-20T16:52:33.745-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: 
Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-09-20T16:52:33.745-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          
Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-09-20T16:52:33.745-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-09-20T16:52:33.745-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-09-20T16:52:33.745-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: 
soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2017-09-20T16:52:33.747-0500 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing 
full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 
'/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-09-20T16:52:33.747-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for 
connections on port 27017
```

I am not able to move forward after this point.

Comment: The log states that MongoDB has been successfully started and is waiting for client connections. Is that not the goal?

Comment: As others stated looks like mongo is up and running . Use ps command if you really want to make sure mongo is up and running .

Answer (score 0):

From the last line in your log, it can be inferred that mongoDb has started and is waiting for connections.

```
2017-09-20T16:52:33.747-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for 
connections on port 27017
```

Open a new terminal and type, 'mongo'. You will be connected to the mongo shell, where you can type in your queries.